Visual Studio Spell Checker partial words not properly ignored due to capitalisation
I'm writing database code for EF and in the comments, I'm describing PostgreSQL vs SQL. Unfortunately the Visual Studio Spell Checker is treating "Postgre" as a separate word and causing an error, instead of treating it as the whole word.
I have a project specific exclusion.dic, and it's working in general.
I've tried manually adding PostgreSQL to the exclusion.dic but it's ignoring that and continuing to react to Postgre.  If I remove the capitals, and use Postgresql it works.
I don't want to add Postgre as an ignored word, because without the SQL it is a spelling mistake.  Is there any way to make it react to the whole word (without removing the capital SQL) and ignore it instead of requiring me to put a real spelling mistake into the ignored list?
EDIT: I started digging around and found the same issue with yyyyMMddhhmmss and there's no way I can change that capitalisation.
